# How to copy a custom .scss file's .css output to wwwroot in a Blazor app?

Tags: css, visual-studio, sass, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM application that I'd like to have *separate* `.scss` files used for global styling that are *not* component specific CSS isolation files. Those are bundled and available at runtime, so no issue there. I'm looking for getting the transpiled `.css` file from it's corresponding `.scss` source file, and have that `.css` file copied to `wwwroot` so I can link to it in `index.html`.

To hedge this a bit, I understand there already exists in `wwwroot` an `app.css` file where additional global styles can be applied. The problem with this is it's a `.css` file and I'd like the power of SASS so this isn't the option I'd like to use. You also can't put a `.scss` file inside `wwwroot` as it's not proper because files that need transpiled need to be  in the project itself; `wwwroot` is a target for static files to be hosted, not raw `.scss` source files.

I'm leveraging LibSassBuilder to transpile my `.scss` files to `.css` so that's all taken care of. In this example I have a `custom.scss` that's been transpiled to `custom.css` and ready for use, but I need it copied to `wwwroot`. It's been a while since I've been in VS, so I *thought* I could use the 'Build Action' in combination with 'Copy to Output Directory' to get this static file moved to `wwwroot` during the build, but it's not working. I believe that's more for the build and output but not specific to `wwwroot`.

[image]

I could implement some old school process with Gulp or Grunt to manually copy the `.css` output of these independent styling files to `wwwroot` but it feels verbose. There must be a more streamlined way to designate this styling file should be copied to `wwwroot`.

How can I get this file copied to `wwwroot` as a part of the build, on saving, or some other manner please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried doing it with post build action without problems

```
    <Target Name="CopyCssBundles" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
        <ItemGroup>
            <MyCssBundles Include="scss\test.css" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(MyCssBundles)" DestinationFiles="wwwroot\css\%(Filename)%(Extension)" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" />
    </Target>
```

And Adding the copy to output to the file

[image]

But, it is copied to the project, I don't know if it what you expect

Comment: Awesome this works and was exactly what I was hoping to see (a way in VS to make this happen). Quickly before I mark it complete please, did you have to hand roll that configuration inside the `<Target...>` code you provided, or is there an interface in VS that helps you build out this action? I looked in the project properties and had not seen any way to build this out except manually the way you did.

Comment: If you click on your project name it will open the project xml paste at the end inside project tag. You don't have to see the project properties anymore

Comment: Correct I knew where to put it, I was asking did you have to manually create that XML configuration, or is there a wizard, tool, etc. in VS to assist in creating it?

Comment: I did it manually, I don't know if exists a tool